# Guice 3.0 with Jersey and Async Servlets

Tags: java, servlets, jersey, guice

Trying to build an application that uses `@Suspended` and `AsyncResponse` but cannot get it to work, my app works fine without the use of `AsyncResponse`.

Below is the stacktrace

```
Sep 30, 2014 4:40:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter guiceFilter
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    at com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.servlet.GuiceContainer.initiate(GuiceContainer.java:121)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:321)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:376)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:559)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.init(ServletDefinition.java:117)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.init(ManagedServletPipeline.java:82)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.initPipeline(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:102)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.init(GuiceFilter.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4775)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5452)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Were you able to figure out a workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your error, but AFAIK Guice does not support async servlets: https://github.com/google/guice/issues/650

Follows my Jersey setup with Guice, in case it's usefull.

The module I need to install on Guice:

```
import javax.inject.Singleton;

import org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider;

import com.sun.jersey.guice.JerseyServletModule;
import com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.servlet.GuiceContainer;
import com.company.internal.app.ws.example.HelloWorld;

public class ApplicationRestModule extends JerseyServletModule {

    @Override
    protected void configureServlets() {
        super.configureServlets();
        serve("/rest/*").with(GuiceContainer.class);

        // Binding services
        bind(HelloWorld.class);

        bind(JacksonJsonProvider.class).in(Singleton.class);
    }
}
```

A service example:

```
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorld {

    @GET
    @Path("/echo/{input}")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String ping(@PathParam("input") String input) {
        return input;
    }

    @POST
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Path("/jsonBean")
    public Response modifyJson(JsonBean input) {
        input.setVal2(input.getVal1());
        return Response.ok().entity(input).build();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!